# jquery - Making content draggable - not waiting until content in iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Basically I have an image and once image is pressed it injects html into a iframe, I then wanted to make content draggable, however my javascript code is either not waiting for content to be loaded or the is an error with my code.

View:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Best programmer ever')
@section('content')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') !!}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('/js/template.js') !!}"></script>
@endsection
        @section('template')
        <div class= "template_class">
            @foreach ($templates as $template)
        <a class="content-link" href="{{ asset($template->file )}}">
        <img id = "image" src="{{ asset($template->image )}}"/>
        </a>
            @endforeach
        </div>
            <iframe id="content-link2"></iframe>
@endsection
@show
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
   $('.content-link').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#content-link2').attr("src",$(this)[0].href);
       console.log($('#content-link2'));
   return false;
   });
});
  $( function() {
    var $currentIframe = $('#content-link2');
   $currentIframe.contents().find('#content').draggable();
   console.log($currentIframe.contents().find('#content'));
});
```

Template, this is a stuff loaded into a iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Template 1</title>

  <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">Insert your content here</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Put your draggable code in the iframe page. You aren't accounting for the new iframe page to load. Iframe content exists in a completely different window

Comment: Problem with that is that I will only be able to drag in the iframe page, however what if a box is outside of iframe and I want to put it in the iframe

Comment: That is extremely complicated trying to even do that. If that's why you switched to iframes from ajax it was a big mistake

Comment: If i attach the code in a iframe itself am I not giving customers code that they don't need to see? in terms of security?

Comment: No idea what you mean. But if you plan to use iframe as if it's part of main page and move things around between the two you will have huge and complicated event handling issues

Comment: I am still using ajax however I could not make the content appear on the page that's why I used iframe, so what is your suggestion on this?